# What is difference between setTimeout with function and without function ?

Tags: javascript

If I consider console.log as a function then what is difference between following this two ?

```
setTimeout(console.log('Test'), 1000);
```

and

```
setTimeout(function(){ console.log('Test'); } , 1000);
```

Reason for asking this second one call properly after 1 second but first call immediately.

Comment: you are passing the result of the `console.log` call to setTimeout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter of `setTimeout` requires a function. When you pass in `console.log('Test')`, it will evaluate `console.log('Test')` FIRST, and passes the result of that into the actual timeout procedure. In your case, `console.log('Test')` doesn't actually return a function, so when evaluating `console.log('Test')`, it will print `test` to the console, then 1 second later, do nothing (since you passed nothing to the `setTimeout` function.

In the second you actually pass a function for it to perform after 1 second, which gives you the result you want.

You can imagine the function to look something like this:

```
function setTimeout(functionToCall, timeToWait) {
    // Some waiting procedure based on timeToWait
    functionToCall();
}
```

**Disclaimer** this is not what the function actually looks like.

In the first case, JS will first call `console.log('Test')`, and pass the result `undefined` into `setTimeout`. This leads to it being printed immediately. In the second case, the entire function is passed into the `setTimeout` without being evaluated first.